# deleting numbers from a list if they are too close to the preceding number

Tags: python, zip

i need to generate a list of numbers (that will represent time points) that show poisson distribution and then go back through the list and delete any numbers that occur (60/300) after the previous number.

So far i have generated this code:

```
a = range(1,20000,100)
b = range(1,4500,10)

list_of_numbers=[]
for i in a:    
    for j in b:    
        i = float(random.expovariate(j)*10000)
        list_of_numbers.append(i)

list_of_numbers.sort()

max_diff_between_numbers = float(60/300)

final_number_list = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(list_of_numbers[1:],list_of_numbers[:-1]) if (x-y)>max_diff_between_numbers]
```

Currently, sing this zip function x-y is returning as 0.0 for each x-y and i can't seem to improve it. any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `max_diff_between_numbers` is set to 0:

```
>>> float(60/300)
0.0
```

What you probably want is:

```
>>> 60/float(300)
0.2
```

Comment: Or ``60/300.0`` or just ``0.2`` directly.

Comment: Integer division strikes again. It's getting clearer day by day that it was a good idea to change that behaviour in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title of your question, I take it you meant min_diff_between_numbers not max.
Anyway, zipping preceding values together may be a problem if, lets say:
[(A, B), (C, D)] where (A, B) fails, (C, D) fails, but (B, C) passes or (A, D) passes.

So basically, the algorithm has to check the difference against the last passed value, not a predetermined pair. I believe list comprehensions cannot address themselves while being created, so it has to be done in 2 stages.

```
import random

a = range(1, 20000, 100)
b = range(1, 4500, 10)

list_of_numbers=[]
for i in a:    
    for j in b:    
        i = float(random.expovariate(j) * 10000)
        list_of_numbers.append(i)

list_of_numbers.sort()

min_diff_between_numbers = 60.0 / 300

final_number_list = list_of_numbers[:1]
[final_number_list.append(x) for x in list_of_numbers[1:] if((x - final_number_list[-1]) > min_diff_between_numbers)]
```